# Visual Studio 2022 Intellisense XML documentation started failing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense, visual-studio-2022, xml-documentation

I've been working on a long and convoluted C++ project in Visual Studio 2022, so I've been making sure to comment as much as possible and have been using the XML documentation summaries for most every function.

These summaries are supposed to show up in IntelliSense when writing the function, and then the parameter summaries should show up when in the spot for that parameter.

Up until today everything had been working pretty much fine, it was always finnicky, but mostly it worked. Today however it all stopped showing up, so I tried following some recommendations from past posts, turning on or off the generation of an XML file, parameter information for C++, and restarting Visual Studio. Nothing has fixed it.

I have managed to find a random portion of my code in which summaries show up for some reason, but even there they're the wrong ones.

[image: A function with a clearly visible summary above it, which doesn't show the summary]

[image: A function with a clearly visible summary above it, but which shows a completely different summary]

Does anyone know of any way to fix this issue? I really need these summaries.

EDIT:
Here's a screenshot of my C++ Intellisense settings
[image: My C++ Intellisense settings, they should all be on their default values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check settings in Tools > Options >Text Editor >C/C++ > Advanced > Intellisense:
[image]
If it doesn’t work you can try to Reset all settings under Tools > Import and Export Settings

Comment: Checked the list of Intellisense settings, none seem to relate to XML documentation as far as I can tell.
Also tried resetting my settings like you said as well, but nothing seems to have changed. I've never really touched any settings after all, so they should've already been default anyways.

Comment: Does using “//” instead of ”///“ work? Or remove hidden .vs folder in your project folder and rebuild your project.

Comment: "//" is just regular old comments, but after deleting that .vs folder, stuff seems to be working, looks like that did the trick, thank you very much.